# How to get index of multiple elements of list in python?

Tags: python, list

Let me have a long list:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', ...]
```

I want to get the indices of all `'a'`. Unfortunately, `l.index('a')` will only output the index of `'a'`'s first occurrence.

I can get them by doing:

```
[idx for idx,i in enumerate(l) if i == 'a']
```

Is that the common way, or there is a built-in function?

*I am thinking when to use `.index` if it only outputs the index of the first occurrence.*

Comment: yep the comprehension is an idomatic way

Comment: Your list comprehension is how I would write it, too.

Comment: I would have gave you the solution you posted

Comment: You can pass a parameter to [**`list.index`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), to say where to search from. By default it searches from the beginning.